# Would turning off windows startup service type that ensure the service will not run on system starting up

Tags: windows, security

Would turning off windows startup services type ensure the service will not run on boot?

e.g. I'd like to close a software services but I afraid of it could be stay somewhere in computer and still using pc resources.

[image: image link]

Comment: "turning off" isn't a valid mode for windows services. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The marked services on the image are all services provided by Windows itself (most of them are mandatory for Windows). You should only disable them if you understand what each service does and that it does not affect your Windows installation. Otherwise you may end up in an defect Windows installation or other strange errors may occur.